# maven - missing artifact error

Tags: maven, dependencies

i installed my eclipse project (dcmfileer) to local repo and tried to depend on the resource from another project. maven claims "missing artifact error". 
i can find the file in the search dialog of the pom dependencies adding site. i can see the file on inside the repo.

i unchecked "resolve dependencies from workspace projects" because i want to use the configuration in different workspaces.

settings.xml contains: ${user.home}/.m2/repository

somebody an idea why its not working?[image: dependencies pom.xml]

[image: local repository view]

[image: eclipse build path properties]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stabilit</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dcm</groupId>
      <artifactId>dcmFileer</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\target</directory>
    <finalName>Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\stabilit\projects\EUREX\DCM\java\Test\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

POM inside the repository - of the dependency (dcmFileer)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.dcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>dcmFileer</artifactId>
    <name>dcmFileer</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://www.stabilit.ch</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>
    <issueManagement>
    </issueManagement>
    <organization>
        <name>STABILIT Informatik AG</name>
        <url>www.stabilit.ch</url>
    </organization>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- switch on dependency-driven aggregation -->
                    <includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>

                    <dependencySourceIncludes>
                        <dependency-source>org.serviceconnector.*</dependency-source>
                    </dependencySourceIncludes>

                    <excludePackageNames>org.serviceconnector.cln</excludePackageNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sourceforge-releases</id>
            <name>Sourceforge Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Could please share your pom.xml

Comment: i just added two poms. first one of the project which is depending on the resource, second one is the pom laying in the repository of the resource. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you realize that (on Linux and other Unix variants) `${user.home}` would get expanded to something like `C:\Documents and Settings\JTraber`, right?

I suspect at this point you have to repos, one under your actual user home, and one under the project workspace. You need to configure Eclipse's Maven plugin to use the repository under your actual `${user.home}`

Also, you are on Windows. The `${}` variables don't get interpolated by the operating system. Instead, you have to use the Windows style, i.e. `%HOMEPATH%`. I suspect you will find an actual directory named `${user.home}` in your project.

Comment: argg..yes your absolutely true, sorry for misunderstanding first. ${user.home} is not going to be substituted so i have two repos one in my eclipse folder and on under my real user home. ${user.home} in settings.xml on win is a bad idea ;).. thanks a lot!!